# Modifying records in one column of a table conditioning on the date ranges in the other table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join, window-functions, partition-by

I am currently trying to combine `Left join` with `window` function (e.g. `partition by class_id order by date_to desc`) to solve the following problem in SQL. It is quite a difficult problem due to a bunch of tricky constraints that come into play, and it seems to me I need to have a way to *choose* which rows from the *partitioned* sub-tables (after applying `windows` function) to go with.

**Problem.** Given two tables A and B having two common fields `class_id` and `prop_id`, our goal is that for **given** parameters `year` and `month` (e.g. 2022-05), the query would include **all** values in the column `class_id` from Table A, change the corresponding value `prop_id` in the same table when certain conditions are satisfied based on the values of `date_to` and `date_from` columns of Table B. The conditions are: if the same value `prop_id` in Table B has `date_from` and `date_to` between the given parameters `year` and `month`, then we set the `prop_id` in Table A to `Null` for that particular `class_id`. Note that a specific `class_id` in Table B might have **multiple** `prop_id,` so we need to determine the exact pair of `date_from` and `date_to` that contains the given parameters `year` and `month`.

Sample Inputs

```
Table A  
         class_id   prop_id   
         12         aa_13         
         13         ab_21
         22         ac_11
         53         bb_32
         48         ac_57

Table B
         class_id   prop_id  date_from     date_to 
         12         aa_13    2022-02-15    2022-12-10
         12         aa_31    2021-09-30    2022-02-12  
         13         ac_12    2021-05-18    2022-02-05
         22         ac_11    2022-05-12    2022-08-25     
         22         ac_12    2022-01-05    2022-04-23
         22         ac_13    2021-08-18    2021-11-16
         53         bb_32    2022-02-06    2022-03-19
         53         bb_31    2021-05-08    2022-02-05
         48         ac_57    2022-02-03    2022-05-07
```

Now, if given `year = 2022` and `month = 5`, then the expected output is

```
Table A  
         class_id   prop_id (modified properly)   
         12         aa_13         
         13         NULL -- 2022-05 > date_to = 2022-02-05
         22         NULL -- 2022-05 could be between 2022-04-23 and 2022-05-11, which is outside the range between 2022-05-12 and 2022-08-25 => NULL is chosen here
         53         NULL -- Same reasoning as for class_id = 22
         48         NULL - 2022-05 could be beyond 2022-05-07 => set it to NULL.
```

**Question.** How can I write a query to achieve the above expected output?

Comment: What does "date_from and date_to between the given parameters year and month" mean? E.g. for year=2022 and month=5: does it mean date_from <= 2022-05-31 and date_to >= 2022-05-01 ?

Comment: That is the correct interpretation for year=2022 and month=5. The `date_from` and `date_to` in Table B mark the time period where a particular `class_id` corresponds to the `prop_id.` We only change the `prop_id` to `NULL` if there is certain days within a given month and year where the class_id is NOT mapped to any prop_id. Does it make better sense now?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a tag for the DB engine, so first is for Postgres, and then Snowflake as per your comment.

**Postgres:**

> ```
> create table "public"."a" (
>   class_id int4, 
>   prop_id text
> );
>
> create table "public"."b" (
>   class_id int, 
>   prop_id varchar,
>   date_from date,
>   date_to date
> );
>
> insert into public.a(class_id,prop_id) values
> (12,'aa_13'),
> (13,'ac_21'),
> (22,'ac_11'),
> (53,'bb_32'),
> (48,'ac_57');
>
> insert into b values
> (12,'aa_13','2022-02-15','2022-12-10'),
> (12,'aa_31','2021-09-30','2022-02-12'),
> (13,'ac_12','2021-05-18','2022-02-05'),
> (22,'ac_11','2022-05-12','2022-08-25'),
> (22,'ac_12','2022-01-05','2022-04-23'),
> (22,'ac_13','2021-08-18','2021-11-16'),
> (53,'bb_32','2022-02-06','2022-03-19'),
> (53,'bb_31','2021-05-08','2022-02-05'),
> (48,'ac_57','2022-02-03','2022-05-07');
>
> select
>   a.class_id, 
>   a.prop_id,
>   case 
>       when b.date_from <= make_date(2022,5,1) and b.date_to >= make_date(2022,5,1) + '1 month - 1 day'::interval
>       then a.prop_id 
>       else null 
>   end modified_prop_id
> from a left join b on a.prop_id = b.prop_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> class_id | prop_id | modified_prop_id
> -------: | :------ | :---------------
>       12 | aa_13   | aa_13           
>       22 | ac_11   | null            
>       13 | ac_21   | null            
>       48 | ac_57   | null            
>       53 | bb_32   | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5e39036ed264b332bb8b0f68949f0c71)*

**Snowflake:**

```
create or replace table a (
    class_id number(38,0),
    prop_id varchar(100)
);

create or replace table b (
    class_id number(38,0),
    prop_id varchar(100),
    date_from date,
    date_to date
);

insert into public.a(class_id,prop_id) values
(12,'aa_13'),
(13,'ac_21'),
(22,'ac_11'),
(53,'bb_32'),
(48,'ac_57');

insert into b values
(12,'aa_13','2022-02-15','2022-12-10'),
(12,'aa_31','2021-09-30','2022-02-12'),
(13,'ac_12','2021-05-18','2022-02-05'),
(22,'ac_11','2022-05-12','2022-08-25'),
(22,'ac_12','2022-01-05','2022-04-23'),
(22,'ac_13','2021-08-18','2021-11-16'),
(53,'bb_32','2022-02-06','2022-03-19'),
(53,'bb_31','2021-05-08','2022-02-05'),
(48,'ac_57','2022-02-03','2022-05-07');
      
select
    a.class_id, 
    a.prop_id,
    case 
        when b.date_from <= date_from_parts(2022,5,1) and b.date_to >= last_day(date_from_parts(2022,5,1))
        then a.prop_id 
        else null 
    end modified_prop_id
from a left join b on a.prop_id = b.prop_id;
```

Comment: Did you test your query?

Comment: Nevermind, my solution is for Postgres

Comment: Could you adapt it somehow to make it work on Snowflake?

Comment: @user177196, adapted for Snowflake. Basically, it's almost the same as for Postgres, cause it's mostly a standard SQL. The only part that differs is for constructing date range for your example, 2022-05.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select Distinct class_id
  From TableB
  Where date_from <= '2022-05-01'
        and date_to >= '2022-05-31'
)

Select A.class_id, 
       IF(C.class_id IS NULL, NULL, A.prop_id) prop_id
From 
TableA A Left Join CTE C
on A.class_id = C.class_id
```

The `CTE` will collect all `class_id`s from `TableB` where any `prop_id` is fitted with the specified condition.

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0d9c76f0c36f52ce90fadc17ba19243) (using MySql 8.0).